# Convert HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap() [Map<String, String[]>] to Map<String, List<String>> using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

From the URL "http://localhost:8988/demo?textSearch=*&cores=&cores=core1&cores=core2&cores=core3&cores=core4&cores=core5&SBU=6&Lab_Office=06&name=Mohammad&name=Hussain&name=Yaseer"

I store the values to map with following code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> urlMap = new HashMap<>();

// store all URL param and get all non empty/null values -> urlMap
request.getParameterMap().forEach((key, val) -> {
     urlMap.put(key, Arrays
           .stream(val)
           .filter(value -> value != null && value.length() > 0)
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
     );
});
```

the above code produces:

```
textSearch=[*]
cores=[core1, core2, core3, core4, core5]
Lab_Office=[06]
SBU=[6]
name=[Mohammad, Hussain, Yaseer]
```

I don't want to use **urlMap.put** instead can we collect values using `.collect()` or any better approach like and store to MAP.

```
Map<String, List<Double>> UrlMapValues =
      parm.entrySet().stream()
          .collect((key, list) -> {
               key, Arrays
                  .stream(list)
                  .filter(val -> val != null && value.length() > 0)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
          });
```

*note: request.getParameterMap() return Map<String, String[]>*

Comment: So you just want to convert `Map<String, String[]>` to `Map<String, List<String>>`?

Comment: good catch, the String[] array has empty values which should be ignored.

Comment: Sure, you can use `collect()` along with a grouping collector: `getParameterMap().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> Arrays.asList(e.getValue())))` (add any filtering before the collect and note that you're dealing with a stream of `Map.Entry<String, String[]>` instances)

Comment: Then just filter it out using Stream API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to collect by passing the key function and then the function to map the value part.

```java
Predicate<String> isValid = s -> s!=null && s.length() > 0;

// separated the valuemapper part for more readability.
Function<Entry<String, String[]>, List<String>> valueMapper = entry -> Arrays.stream(entry.getValue())
      .filter(isValid)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<String, List<String>> UrlMapValues = request.getParameterMap().entrySet()
                         .stream()
                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, valueMapper));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the `Map<String, String[]>` to `Map<String, List<String>>` like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = request.getParameterMap()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> Arrays.asList(entry.getValue())));
```

#### Edit

If a mutable list is required in the result map then wrap the immutable list returned in the valueMapper with `new ArrayList<>()`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = requestParams
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()))));
```

Thanks to Yassin for pointing this out.

Comment: Nice answer, however you should also tell him that his `List<String>`has now become immutable, and no changes can be made to its state

Answer (score 1):

from @[Thomas] comment,
Removes all empty values from array and store in MAP<String, List>:

```
Map<String, List<String>> UrlMapValues = request.getParameterMap().entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                           Map.Entry::getKey, list -> Arrays
                                .stream(list.getValue())
                                .filter(value -> value != null && value.length() > 0)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        )
                );
```